# Notepad ++ вставка текста в мультилисты

Tags: notepad++

есть листов 300 с разным кодом в Notepad ++ - каждый код в начале это плюс-минус один и тот же Select - можно ли как-то массово вставить дополнительную строку в каждый лист ?

Comment: что такое "лист"?

Comment: ну или новая вкладка

Comment: вы понимаете, что эти ваши "лист" и "новая вкладка" это всего лишь самые банальные текстовые файлы?

Comment: да ))
но я пробовал такую операцию сделать нотпадом - если есть другой способ, то здорово